# Warning: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

Tags: php, php-ini

I seem to have developed a slight issue with one of my plugins and am currently getting this error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

The first solution I tried was to change allow_url_fopen to enabled in the server configuration but this didn't solve anything, I then did a test to see if it is actually showing as on and it is.

I even tried adding `ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);` to see if that would solve it but I'm still getting the issue.

Is there something I haven't tried?

Comment: Did you restart the web-server after changing the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered my own question here.

I have multiple sites on the same server, so switching it on just a subdomain did nothing. To solve this I had to edit the PHP version in MultiPHP INI Editor.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php), `allow_url_fopen` is `PHP_INI_SYSTEM`, what [means](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php):

> Entry can be set in `php.ini` or `httpd.conf`

This makes sense: the directive is a security feature so users should not be able to override it.

Since `ini_set()` is PHP code you are not setting it in any of the aforementioned configuration files, which are the only allowed locations.

Comment: I did also try setting it in php.ini. This also does nothing

Comment: That's a rather vague description. Did you edit the correct file? What syntax did you use? Did you restart the appropriate processes?